# BST: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I was trying to implement a BST in C++.This is a specific member function to perform in order traversal and return a vector with the elements of the tree. 
Now the problem arises with the stack pop() function which I set to the current node.
   `void value not ignored as it ought to be`

I understand that the empty stack will return a void value after the preceding pop() call.But then what's the solution to this, cause  it's required in this [traversal algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order) to retrieve the last node from the stack.

```
vector <int> BSTree::in_order_traversal()
{

vector <int> list;
stack <Node *> depthStack;
Node * cur = root;

while ( !depthStack.empty() || cur != NULL ) {
                if (cur != NULL) {
                         depthStack.push(cur);
                         cur = cur->left;
                                                     }
                else                             {
                         cur = depthStack.pop(); // Heres the line 
                         list.push_back(cur->key);
                         cur = cur->right;
                                                      }

                                                                                                                                            }
return list;

}
```

Comment: You're doing something in your code with the "return value" of a void-returning function. Stop doing that it makes no sense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++ the method

```
std::stack::pop()
```

doesn't return the value removed from the stack. The reason is that there's no way in general to write such a function correctly from an exception-safety point of view.

You need to store the value first and then remove it with `pop`... e.g.

```
Node *x = depthStack.top();
depthStack.pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ stack.pop() function doesn't return the value from the stack.

So ,first you store the values and then you pop it.
In your case:

---

```
vector <int> BSTree::in_order_traversal()
{

vector <int> list;
stack <Node *> depthStack;
Node * cur = root;

while ( !depthStack.empty() || cur != NULL ) {
                if (cur != NULL) {
                         depthStack.push(cur);
                         cur = cur->left;
                                                     }
                else                             {
                         cur = depthStack.top();   //solution
                                 depthStack.pop();                             
                         list.push_back(cur->key);
                         cur = cur->right;
                                                      }

                                                                                                                                            }
return list;

}
```